# auto login Azure powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

Every time I open a azure powershell windows is it possible to auto login ?

i.e. this command given below should run everytime I open Azure Command window.

Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile (path in local machine)

or even 
Add-AzureAccount

Answer (score 9):

You can actually do it. Follow this process:

Open the Azure PowerShell initialization file at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Services\ShortcutStartup.ps1" for 64-bit OS or "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Services\ShortcutStartup.ps1" for 32-bit OS.

Add the following code just after the statement `$VerbosePreference="Continue"`

```
$username = "<username>"
$password = "<password>"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($userName, $secpasswd)
Add-AzureAccount -Credential $cred
```

That should do the auto login for you

@Update: For Azure ARM mode, the command would be `Login-AzureRMAccount -Credential $cred`. This might not work with Microsoft accounts though.

Comment: it should be noted that this doesn't work if you are signing in with MS account.

Comment: These files don't exist on my Azure VM. Are they in a new place now?

Comment: @sheriffpony, these files were present in Azure Web and Worker roles automatically. Azure VMs do not include Azure PowerShell cmdlets by default as far as I know. You'll have to install them manually before you want to use the commands. If you have access to PowerShell gallery, you can just use `Install-Module Azure` or `Install-Module AzureRM`. If not, you have to install them manually or using some form of automated scripting such as PowerShell DSC.

Answer (score 3):

Once you use the use the Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile the data from there is saved in a subscription data file in the user's profile (by default at : %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Windows Azure Powershell\WindowsAzureProfile.xml).  It also takes the certificate with the private key from the settings file and saves it into the machine's certificate store so that the subscription data file only contains the thumbprint for the cert.  That subscription data file is then *used even across sessions so that you don't have to keep importing*.  Using the -SubscriptionDataFile parameter you can actually write the file to a different location if you want.

Note that this also means that anyone that can get access to your machine and open a PowerShell windows will be able to use your cmdlets to affect any/all subscriptions that are imported in this manner.

One thing to note here is that if you are keeping your Publish Settings file around you have a file which has a complete copy of the private key to your manage certificate.  If that file were to be taken from you without you realizing it someone would then have all they need to possibly do irrevocable harm to your subscription.  I'd recommend keeping a copy of the SubscriptionDataFile instead once the certificate has been loaded into the machine's certificate store.  You can then use Set-AzureSubscription and point to the subscription data file to pull in the subscriptions if they get removed for some reason.

If you use the Add-AzureAccount, once you log in, it will also store pretty much the same data in the same file; however, it is keeping track of the token from Azure AD.  That means that eventually the token will expire and you'd have to log in again anyway.  Currently using the Add-AzureAccount is good for interactive scripts only as in PowerShell there isn't a good way to store or pass the credentials that I'm aware of.

So, if you use the import publish settings file you shouldn't have to keep importing unless you've done a remove-azuresubscription or that subscription data file has been removed.  If you are using PowerShell 3 the Azure Module should be automatically loaded for you unless you've turned off autoload.

Comment: Add-AzureAccount expires after 12 hours. But not sure when Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile expires . Next day morning(system shutdown + start) when I opened Azure powershell I was logged out. and had to do Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile again

Comment: That's interesting, I've not seen that behavior in regards to the subscription data imported using the publish settings file and PowerShell. Are you sure that a remove-azuresubscription wasn't run, or perhaps the subscription data file wasn't somehow removed between the sessions? When you say you were logged out, what error did it give you when you typed a command?

Comment: I should also point out that I don't use the "Azure PowerShell" shortcut, I just start up a regular PowerShell window and the Azure module is auto loaded.  If you are using the shortcut called "Windows Azure PowerShell perhaps that does something different.

Comment: when I try get-azuresubscription I get 2 . 1) Add-AzureAccount -Hotmail one 2) Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile. And you are right, the import-AzurePublishSettingsFile did not expire but it did not allow me to do anything because of Add-AzureAccount expiry and I was forced to login again and it worked. I think I should remove the the first one with remove-Azuresubscription.

Comment: Likely the one that was from Add-AzureAccount was the default.  If you remove it, or if you use Select-AzureSubscription to switch the default to the publish settings file one it would use that one. Of course, if these are somehow the same subscription you only need one of them. If these are difference subscriptions then you'd need to import the settings file for the other one if you don't want to have to log in for that one.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are asking for is to authenticate to Azure from Powershell, without having to provide your username and password - which is your service administrator credentials.

A way to do that is to create what is called a Service Principal. This concept is to authenticate to Azure, not as a service administrator - which requires you to enter credentials, but as a service account which has the same permissions.

[Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/) is how you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines to your Powershell profile file (*C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1*)

```
Import-Module azure;
Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile YourPath
Add-AzureAccount YourAccount
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, startign with release 4.4.0, you can do this:

```
Enable-AzureRmContextAutosave
```

and your credentials will automatically be persisted across sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You can auto login to Azure by setting up a PowerShell profile.

You can include any commands you want in the profile and when you start PowerShell, all those will automatically run and be ready for you.

To Setup PowerShell profile and import Azure modules:

1. To import Azure modules, Install Powershell SDK from here - https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx/getinstaller/WindowsAzurePowershellGet.3f.3f.3fnew.appids
2. Open PowerShell in Administrator mode and run below cmd to check if you have a profile already setup or not

   > > test-path $profile

   ```
   i.  If the O/P is False, you don’t have a profile. Go to step 3
   ii. If the O/P is True, you already have a profile setup. Go to step 4
   ```
3. In the same PowerShell window, follow these cmds

   > > New-item –type file –force $profile
   > >
   > > Notepad $profile

   ```
   i. In the notepad, type 

       >> Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM\5.6.0\AzureRM.psm1"  (Note: this path might change in future release, verify before you put in)
       >> Login-AzureRmAccount -verbose

   ii. Save and close the notepad
   ```
4. In the same PowerShell window, follow these cmds

   > > Notepad $profile

   ```
   i. In the notepad, type 

      >> Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Azure.psd1"
      >> Login-AzureRmAccount -verbose

   ii. Save and close the notepad
   ```

Feel free to add any commands you would like in the profile after Login-AzureRmAccount

Hope this help!