# Azure ARM Template Deployment Without Template Linking

Tags: .net, templates, azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm having trouble finding documentation (although there seems to be hints) on how to deploy AzRM templates in a .Net application using Azure.Resource.Manager without requiring the use of Template Links.  I want to generate templates on the fly and deploy from an in-memory template and parameters file, is this possible?

Comment: Do you expect C# code or PowerShell script in the answer you're looking for? I have the solutions for both.

Comment: Trying template-less C# based deployments that can be runtime configured based on user interaction

Comment: What do you mean by template-less deployment? ARM deployment is basically template-based?

Comment: @tafaju Do you still have a need for a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to call into the Azure powershell. Then you can just write your ARM template to a file, and deploy that file with:

```
Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureResourceManager    
New-AzureResourceGroup -name <resource group name> -Location 'westus' -TemplateFile <json file location>
```

To do the auth use `Add-AzureAccount` and switch to the sub that you want to use with `Select-AzureSubscription`.

To call that cmdlet unattended see: [auto login Azure powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267516/auto-login-azure-powershell)

Comment: Attempting to do this without powershell so I can use C# Class Libraries, I'm also trying to do template-less deployments so I they can be runtime configurations rather than pre-ordained or pushing files up to blog storage.